# submit pressed then loaded function

Tags: php

login.php

```
<?php
class airsystem{
     public function login(){
      echo "check login";
     }
}
 $airsystem = new airsystem;
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
    require_once ("login.php");
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $airsystem->login();
    }
?>

<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

my intention is to make the login system and the function only runs when i clicked submit, it mean "check login" only show if i click submit button. but the echo always there even i am not pressing the submit.

so mean it auto load the function , how i going to achieve that ??

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not clear, but my sixth sense says putting require_once inside if block is the answer. Looks like you have difficulty in using English. That's fine but could you try again to rewrite this question to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: What's the HTML code associated with that?

Comment: sorry i try edit again

Comment: @rineez - From what I could make out the original poster wishes to know why `check login` is always visible, regardless of wether the submit was pressed. Not bad English relative to many posts here lol!

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly isset on a $_POST will cause you problems as it can be set but empty. Try using this which will ensure submit is set and populated:

```
<?php

if( !empty($_POST['submit']) ){

  require_once ("login.php");
  $airsystem->login();

}

?>
```

Additionally it is worth only including the login script if it is required (the user has pressed the button). (As suggested by @rineez)

Comment: @user3233074 Please mark this as the answer if this helped solve your problem.